# Show text from rows in MySQL database equal 0 and 1?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, rows, fetch

I can't get my code to show text from the MySQL database where it equals 0 and 1. Where it says "/* 1 = logged in */" I want it to show the results from where 'privileges' equals 0 and 1, but I can't find out how.

```
   <?php
if (isset($_SESSION['username']))
   {
   if($_SESSION['privileges'] == '1') /* 1 = logged in */
    {
    $sql="SELECT * FROM `navbar`";
    $sql2=mysql_query($sql)
          or die("Couldn't etablish connection with
                 the server or username wasn't found 
                 in the database.");
    $count=mysql_num_rows($sql2);
    if($count > 0)
     {
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql2)) {
        if(($row['privileges'] == '0') or ($row['privileges'] == '1'))
          {
           echo '<li><a href="', $row["url"], '">', $row["text"], '</a></li>';
          }
      }
     }else{
          die("Could't find 'navbar' table in database.");
     }
    }
    else if($_SESSION['privileges'] == '2') /* 2 = vip */
         {
          include('./navbar_vip.php');
         }
          else if($_SESSION['privileges'] == '3')  /* 3 = supporter */
           {
            include('./navbar_support.php');
           }
            else if($_SESSION['privileges'] == '99')  /* 99 = administrator */
             {
             include('./navbar_admin.php');
             }
      }
?>
```

Comment: What is the output? Are you getting the "Couldn't find 'navbar' table in database." message?

Comment: `if ($_SESSION['privileges'] == '1' || $_SESSION['privileges'] == '0')`?

Comment: I don't see session_start() anywhere...

Comment: It's included and I'm getting data, just not the ones from the "$row['privileges'] == '1')". :)

Comment: Do you mean you're getting results from the database? Are you getting all users that have $row["privileges"] == 0 but no results for $row["privileges"] == 1?

Comment: It's included and I'm getting data. It just wont get the data from "($row['privileges'] == '0')" I think it's this line, maybe another way to make it take both:
"if(($row['privileges'] == '0') or ($row['privileges'] == '1'))"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all 
you need to

1. -catch $_SESSION['privileges']  like  `isset($_SESSION['privileges'])`
2. instead of 3 else if, use a switch

   ```
   switch($_SESSION['privileges']){
   case 1: /* logged */
     ...
     default: /* not logged in */

   }
   ```
3. change `if(($row['privileges'] == '0') or ($row['privileges'] == '1'))`

   if(($row['privileges'] == '0') || ($row['privileges'] == '1'))

the "or" is only for dying what you mean is the OR-Operator : "||"

Comment: So instead of making the "if (isset($_SESSION['username']))" you want me to use if (isset($_SESSION['privileges'])).
Then I can make the cases. But how should that help me with the gathering the specific data from the rows?

Comment: no, but you must be sure that "privileges" exists, maybe check both

Comment: I already checked, else I won't get data. I only get the data from "$_SESSION['privileges'] == '0')" and not the ones from "$_SESSION['privileges'] == '1')". :)

Comment: I've re-coded all my code into the switch method and made some other things and now I found a way to my results and stuff! Soo I'll mark this as the answer. :)